# Regex for finding the index of Mathematical Operators

Tags: regex, scala, postfix-notation

I am writing a program that takes a string of a mathematical expression, converts it to postfix notation. Which I have done, I am now trying to figure out how to evaluate this expression. I have left it in the data type of a queue, so my idea is to try and find the index of the first operator, then find the two numbers the come before it, send those to a new function which will evaluate them based on which operator is found (so one function for adding, one for subtracting ... etc). Im having trouble figuring out how to grab the index though.

Im trying to use the Queue method of `indexOf` and then passing it a regex for those operators. using `\\W`

y is a Queue. i've never used this type of character code before.

```scala
var z = y.indexOf("[\\W]")
```

i would like it to return the index of the first operator, in the case i currently have it is a "+"
currently that doesent find anything. i've also tried dropping those brackets an example Queue is

```
Queue(-1, 2, 3, *, +, 10, +)
Queue(1, 2, +)
```

which does mean i need a way to differ if its just a - or if its tied to the number. These are all Strings inside of the Queue

Comment: Can you show a sample of the expected input (aka what is the value of `y`)?

Comment: You may be interested in [this](https://books.underscore.io/scala-with-cats/scala-with-cats.html#exercise-post-order-calculator).

Answer (score 0):

You have to

```
y.indexWhere(_.matches("\\W"))
```

Comment: My previous comment was in reply to the comment "This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - From Review – ravibagul91", deleted after I replied.  I think that comments posted under "review mode" shouldn't be (allowed to be) deleted unless there are no other reviewers or comment replies.